# Create a vector in a loop for every pair of samples

Tags: r

I do a pairwise calculation between my samples and I want every pairwise calculation to be stored in a separate vector. For 3 comparisons, I have:

```
sample_12 <- vector(mode="numeric", length = 10)
sample_13 <- vector(mode="numeric", length = 10)
sample_23 <- vector(mode="numeric", length = 10)
```

Is there a possibility to create these vectors with the corresponding names in a loop so it can work for any given number of samples?

I tried the following code but I can't access the vectors outside the for-loop, how could I solve this issue?

```
pop = 3
sample = vector(mode="numeric", length = 10)
for (i in 1:(pop - 1)) {
  for (j in (i + 1):pop) {
    name <- paste("sample",i,j, sep = "")
    name <- vector(mode="numeric", length = 10)
  }
}
```

Comment: `combn(x = 3, m = 2)`. You can paste together the columns to get the names you want. I strongly recommend storing the combination vectors in a `list` rather than as separate objects. (And try not to use "list" when you mean "vector".)

Comment: @Gregor Thanks! I added an edit based on your comment. Would you mind having a look at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "assign" function:

```
pop = 3
sample = vector(mode="numeric", length = 10)
pop_combos <- combn(pop, 2)
for (i in 1:ncol(pop_combos)) {
    name <- paste("sample_",
                  pop_combos[,i][1],
                  pop_combos[,i][2],
                  sep="")
    assign(name, sample)
}
```

Outside the loop you can now access the vectors:

```
> sample_12
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list:

```
pop = 3
combinations = apply(combn(pop, m = 2), 2, paste, collapse = "_")

sample = replicate(n = length(combinations), numeric(10), simplify = FALSE)
names(sample) = combinations

sample
# $`1_2`
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 
# $`1_3`
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 
# $`2_3`
#  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You can then access each element of the list, e.g., `sample[["1_3"]]`. This scales up very easily and doesn't require pasting together names and using `assign` and `get`, which is just asking for hard-to-find bugs. You can use `lapply` or for loops to iterate over each item in the list trivially. Depending on your use case, it might make more sense to use the default `simplify = TRUE` inside `replicate` and keep it as a matrix or data frame. The only reason to use a list would be if some of the vectors needed to be different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this you are searching for?

*Please suppose that you save all the vectors as rows/columns in a data.frame*

```
list.values <- list()
col <- ncol(df)
row <- nrow(df)
for( i in 1:(col*row)) {list[[i]] = df - df[i/row,i%%col]}
```

Now you have access to all the data frames in the **list[[*i* * *j*]]**, that are the difference between all the elements and the **element[*i*,*j*]**.

*E.g:* You want to access the values that are made between all the dataframe and the
 `element [2, 3]`. Then, you do this `View(list[[2*3]])`